# Find the supremum and infimum of the set $\left \{\frac{x}{x^2 -1} : x\in \Bbb R, x^2 \neq 1\right \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I know how to find the limit to plus and minus infinity of $\frac{x}{x^2 -1}$, which would be $0$. And the limit at $0$ would also be $0$. But I am having a very hard time visualizing this set and even a harder time finding its supremum and infimum.

WolframAlpha says the the image of $\frac{x}{(x^2 - 1)}$ is $\Bbb R$, therefor I think this set is not limited. But I do not know how to prove that the image is in fact $\Bbb R$ and that the supremum and infimum do not exist.

Comment: To see that the image is all of $\Bbb R$, find the value at (or near) a few key points and use continuity and the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Let $\alpha$ by any real number, can you solve $$\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\alpha$$?

Comment: The elements of the set are $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that...?

Comment: By the way, your title notation does not make sense. You wrote $\left \{x\in \Bbb R: x^2 \neq 1,\frac{x}{x^2 -1}\right \}$, but I think you actually mean $\left \{\frac{x}{x^2 -1} : x\in \Bbb R, x^2 \neq 1\right \}$. The things on the left of the ":" are the elements of the set; the things on the right are the conditions $x$ satisfy.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What does the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x}{x^2-1}=-\infty \quad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac{x}{x^2-1}=\infty$$
tell you about $A$? Can it be bounded?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $x^2$ $\neq$ $1$ means that $x$ $\neq$ $1$ or $-$$1$ but if we get the left and right limits of the function we get $-$$\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively. So we have no supremum or infimum there.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without taking the limit?